# How to fetch data having HTML tags in APIs

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am fetching data from the server and I am trying to integrate it in my app. I am using retrofit2 and Rxjava2 to fetch data from the server. How can I get `included` and `excluded` filed in my app or how can I remove these html tags from the response?

Below is my server response:

```
 {
        "id": "309",
        "state": "62",
        "country": "1",
        "price": "7888",
        "maxprice": "9888",
        "shortdescr": " Port Blair With Same Day Havelock",
        "descr": "",
        "included": "<ul>\r\n\t<li>All accommodation on double / triple sharing</li>\r\n\t<li>Hotel Accommodation</li>\r\n\t<li>Meal Plan CP Breakfast Only.</li>\r\n\t<li>Entrance Fees.</li>\r\n\t<li>Airport Transfer.</li>\r\n\t<li>All Transportation for local sight-seeing tours and airport/ hotel/ by 1 AC Vehicle in Port Blair/Havelock and NAC Vehicle at Neil Island .as per itinerary.</li>\r\n\t<li>Cruise transfers Port Blair &ndash;Havelock &ndash; Portblair by Ferry.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
        "exclude": "<ul>\r\n\t<li>GST 5%</li>\r\n\t<li>Any airfare.</li>\r\n\t<li>Any Meals (If on EPAI).</li>\r\n\t<li>Any personal expense.</li>\r\n\t<li>Any type of insurance.</li>\r\n\t<li>Any claim due to natural calamities.</li>\r\n\t<li>Any other things which are not mentioned in inclusions.</li>\r\n\t<li>Any extra services used by you.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
        "image": "cms_157140016139.png",
        "status": "1",
        "created_date": "2019-10-18",
        "updated_date": "2020-03-12",
        "packages": "2"
    }
```

How can I show data in app?

Comment: why not just save as string and use string.replace to remove these ?

Comment: I am saving it as a string after fetching it from the server but how can I remove those tags.

Comment: by using string.replace

Comment: I would parse response into object using gson or whatever and converter api for retrofit. After you can get included smth like model.getIncluded() and then you can do with this string whatever you want.

Comment: @a_local_nobody could you please give me an example with above response.